# Filter substring by multiple indices position

Tags: python

Given an array of words, Id need to filter those that are at a certain multiple index position with a certain character.

My attempt here:

```
wordList = ['happy', 'hatty', 'dogma', 'hapa']
char = a
list_pos = [1,3] # search for all of this index position, so dogma is not included

# need help here 
for word in wordList:
    x = filter(lambda ch: (ch[i]==char for i in list_pos), word)
    # this just lists all the words
```

final answer should be
`['happy', 'hatty', 'hapa']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `filter` over `wordList` and then keep those for which any of the characters in the places of the indices is true:

```
result = filter(lambda w: any(w[i]==char for i in list_pos), wordList)
```